# Loops in C and how to use it correctly

Tags: loops, for-loop, computer-science

I am currently doing the CD50 online course, and I am having trouble with loops. I know that it starts at 0. And I think that is what is throwing me off.

My assignment is to create "Mario" steps with a number given by the user.
[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7zDx.jpg)

I tried to fix this by starting the loop at 1 rather than 0.
But I would rather understand how to do it properly.

```
int height;
string hash = "#";
string empty = " ";    

do
{
    printf("Height: ");
    height = GetInt();

}
while (height > 23 || height <= 0 );
{
    printf("Height = %i\n", height);

for (int step = 0; step < height; step++)
{

    for(int spaceNumber = height; spaceNumber >= step; spaceNumber--)
    {
      printf("%s",empty);

    }
    for(int hashNumber = 0; hashNumber <= step; hashNumber++)
    {
      printf("%s",hash);

    }

  printf("\n");
}

}
```

}

Comment: You have several errors in your code... the `;` after the first while loop indicates that you will loop forever is condition is true...

Answer (score 0):

After looking at my code again I found that if I keep for (int step = 0; step < height; step++) and add for (int step = 0; step <= height; step++) it works.

Thanks for being my rubber duck no one.....

Comment: If you answered your question you can select yourself as best answer!